# tkinter label textvariable not showing

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am using python 3.7 and tkinter.

I want to display text information which is periodically updated and I want to display it in a table format where each cell is of fixed width. Without going into too many specifics, I am using grid geometry manager.  Unfortunately, the text is not displaying in the cells, and I don't know why.

I understand the construct of my "table"-like GUI is not as simple as it could be. I want to be able to easily hide/show rows, so I have given each row its own frame making it easy to show/hide any row. (I have also used a grid layout within each row as well, thinking that this will be the easiest way to eventually force the geometry manager to give me uniform/non-changing cell widths.)

My first problem is that no text is displaying in my labels in the "table".
I have verified via `print('label text = ', label.cget("textvariable"))`, that the correct textvariable was in fact assigned to the label.

I have read many posts regarding "tkinter label text not showing" and nothing has helped.
Thank you for any insights. Here is the code:

```
driverList = ['bob','fred','ethel']
tracks = ['daytona', 'charlotte', 'atlanta', 'darlington','lasvegas','watkins','talladega']
dynamicAllDriverFlagReportDict = {'bob': ['bob','i','','RevDn','','','',''],
                                  'fred': ['fred','In-Up','','','','RevUp','Ham',''],
                                  'ethel': ['ethel','','RevDn','','','In-Dn','Sht','']
                                  }    
global driverFrameDict    
driverFrameDict= dict() 

# Set up the GUI
window = tk.Tk()

myDataFrame = tk.Frame(master=window)
myDataFrame.pack()
btnFrame= tk.Frame(master=window, bg="gray")
btnFrame.pack(side="bottom")


for driverIndex in range(len(driverList)):
    myOneStockFrame = tk.Frame(master=myDataFrame, height=25, width=800)
    for tfIndex in range(len(tracks)+1):
        oneTFFrame = tk.Frame(master=myOneStockFrame,relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)#, height=25)#, width=8)
        if tfIndex == 0:
            label = tk.Label(master=oneTFFrame,text=driverList[driverIndex])#, height=15, width=8)
        else:
            print('driverIndex=', driverIndex, '; tfIndex=', tfIndex, 'dynamicAllDriverFlagReportDict=', dynamicAllDriverFlagReportDict[driverList[driverIndex]][tfIndex])
            label = tk.Label(master=oneTFFrame,textvariable=dynamicAllDriverFlagReportDict[driverList[driverIndex]][tfIndex])#,height=20)#, width=8)   
            print('label text = ', label.cget("textvariable"))                    
        label.pack()#padx=5,pady=5)
        #label.pack_propagate(0)
        oneTFFrame.grid(row=0,column=tfIndex)#, sticky= "nswe", padx=0, pady=0)
        #oneTFFrame.grid_propagate(0)

    myOneStockFrame.grid(row=driverIndex,column=0)#, sticky= "nswe", padx=0, pady=0)
    #myOneStockFrame.grid_propagate(0)

    driverFrameDict[driverList[driverIndex]] = myOneStockFrame  
    #print('driverFrameDict['+driverList[driverIndex]+'] = ', myOneStockFrame)

window.mainloop()
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Read up on [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: excellent reference. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textvariable` has to be set to an instance of one of the special tkinter variables (`StringVar`, etc). You're passing a string, which causes a new internal variable to be created with a name that matches the string.

Comment: yes, that makes total sense!  Thank you so much. Will  work on implementing...